# "And" some selectors in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a *form* in html. I want to do something(for example hiding the entire form) If input fields were valid and user clicked on button.

Here is what I do but it doesn't work:

```css
#username:valid#password:valid#Next:active{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="login" action="..."  autocomplete="off">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend id="loginLegend">LOGIN:</legend>
          
                    <label for="username" id="usernameLabel">Username:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="text username" value=""><br>
          
                    <label for="password" id="passwordLabel"    class="password">Password:</label><br>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required class="text password"> <br>
          
                    <input type="button" value="Next" id="Next">
                </fieldset>
</form>
```

I know It can be accomplished by JavaScript but I just wonder if we can do it with pure CSS?

DETAIL:
As matter of fact, I don't want to hide the form exactly I want to start an animation over form but I need be sure that user clicked on button and all fields are valid.

Just for simplicity I changed my "animation" to "display: none" because I think I can work out the rest of code on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `~` selector.

In CSS, `~` means *any subsequent sibling*.

---

**Working Example (Version #1):**

```css
#username:valid ~ #password:valid ~ #Next:active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="login" action="..."  autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
<legend id="loginLegend">LOGIN:</legend>
          
<label for="username" id="usernameLabel">Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="text username" value=""><br>
<label for="password" id="passwordLabel"    class="password">Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required class="text password"> <br>
<input type="button" value="Next" id="Next">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

---

You have stated that you would like to use CSS to make the entire form disappear when the `#Next` button is clicked. This can't be achieved with conventional CSS (which only has selectors for *subsequent siblings* and *children*, not for *previous siblings* and *parents*).

But if you were to use a post-processor CSS library like [axe](https://github.com/RouninMedia/axe) then you could use the compound selector:

```
#username:valid ~ #password:valid ~ #Next:active ^ #login
```

where `^` is the any ancestor selector.

---

**N.B.** *The example below only demonstrates a proof-of-concept with the compound selector:*

```
#username ~ #password ~ #Next ^ #login
```

*because the version of **axe** used in the example does not work with pseudo-classes like `:valid` and `:active`.*

---

**Working Example (Version #2):**

```css
#username ~ #password ~ #Next ^ #login {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form id="login" class="login" action="..."  autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
<legend id="loginLegend">LOGIN:</legend>
          
<label for="username" id="usernameLabel">Username:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="text username" value=""><br>
<label for="password" id="passwordLabel"    class="password">Password:</label><br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" required class="text password"> <br>
<input type="button" value="Next" id="Next">
</fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://rouninmedia.github.io/axe/axe.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a better answer but this code doesn't do what I want. I want to hide the entire form but your code  makes just button to hide.

Comment: CSS only has selectors for subsequent siblings and children, not for previous siblings and parents. If you were to use a post-processor CSS library like [**axe**](https://github.com/RouninMedia/axe) then you could use the compound selector: `#username:valid ~ #password:valid ~ #Next:active ^ #login`, where `^` is the _any ancestor selector_.

Comment: Your last example doesn't work for me but your explanation was complete, Thank you.
I just wonder if it is better to use "axe" library or do it by Javascript? I prefer to do it with javascript If it can't be done by pure CSS.

Comment: I would **not** use the _axe_ CSS post-processor library as it stands. It's not production-ready. As you can see above, it cannot handle _pseudo-selectors_ (yet). It's a project I started in Dec 2016, when I was learning about javascript objects and Ajax. I mean to return to it and make it much more robust when I have substantially completed the main project I've been working on since.

Comment: No, No need to get javascript solution, I know how to do it with javascript.
I just wanted to thank you and mention the easier way as an curiosity for who visit this question-answer thread and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Without going into details and the reason why you decided to use this solution, the answer is simple: yes, you can. Separate selectors with a comma character.

```
#username:valid,
#password:valid,
#Next:active {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong, I want to hide form if user clicked on button but your code hide  username as soon as it was valid.
I another word you are doing "OR" operator and not "And".